# Is it true that $\text{Var}(X)=\mathbb E[(X-Y)_{+}^{2}]$ for $Y$ iid to $X$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, independence, variance

Is it true that $\text{Var}(X)=\mathbb E[(X-Y)_{+}^{2}]$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent identically distributed?

Note that $(X-Y)_{+}^{2}$=$(X-Y)^{2}\chi_{\{X\geq Y\}}+0\chi_{\{X< Y\}}$

Why is this true? Any proof?

Comment: Yet another closed question that makes no sense ...please vote to reopen

Comment: @TheBridge the question contains no context. For example, is it a question from a book or course, and if so what was covered in the preceding chapter or lecture?

Comment: The Question is clear there are all tags needed to get it after this if you need more context then what about just ignoring  the post ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $E(X-Y)^{2}_{+}=E(X-Y)^{2}I_{X \geq Y}=E(Y-X)^{2}I_{Y \geq X}$  because $(X,Y)$ is i.i.d. Hence, $E(X-Y)^{2}_{+}=E(X-Y)^{2}I_{Y \geq X}$ which shows that $E(Y-X)^{2}I_{Y \geq X}=\frac  1 2 E(X-Y)^{2}$. Now you can complete the proof by expanding $(X-Y)^{2}$.

[It should be noted that $E(X-Y)^{2}I_{X=Y}=0$]

Comment: I feel like $P(X=Y)$ being positive would throw a spanner in the works here.

Comment: @Arthur No. $(X-Y)^{2}=0$ when $X=Y$ so my argument works.

Comment: Why is the downvoting?